# How do i keep a set of elements wrapped in a div inline?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, inline

https://jsfiddle.net//2L4t9saq/61/ is my code
this is the output of one line of iterations

```
<span class="inline"><div class="pixels" x="1" y="1" style="background-color: red; width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div><div class="pixels" x="2" y="1" style="background-color: red; width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div><div class="pixels" x="3" y="1" style="background-color: red; width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div><div class="pixels" x="4" y="1" style="background-color: red; width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div><div class="pixels" x="5" y="1" style="background-color: red; width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div><div class="pixels" x="6" y="1" style="background-color: red; width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div><div class="pixels" x="7" y="1" style="background-color: red; width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div><div class="pixels" x="8" y="1" style="background-color: red; width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div><div class="pixels" x="9" y="1" style="background-color: red; width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div><div class="pixels" x="10" y="1" style="background-color: red; width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div></span>
```

this creates  10 divs with width/height of 10px with the background color red, all 10 divs are wrapped in the `span` with class `inline`. this process is then repeated 10 times to create the 10*10 array.

this can be configured, currently all that can be configured are the width and height of the array, and the width and height of each individual pixel

currently it is just a vertical 100 block line of red squares.

how would i make all element wrapped in class`inline` stay inline? as to turn it from a 1*100 line to a 10*10 square

thanks in advance

```js
/*
$("#body").append(
"<div x='1'></div>"
);
$("div[x=1]").css("background-color","red")
$("div[x=1]").css("width","16")
$("div[x=1]").css("height","16")
*/
var createGrid = function(dimx, dimy, pixx, pixy) {
  for (var n = 1; n < dimy + 1; n++) {
    var str = "<div class='inline'>"

    for (var i = 1; i < dimx + 1; i++) {
      var opentag = "<div class='pixels' x='"
      var midtag = "' y='"
      var endtag = "'></div>"
      str = str + opentag + i + midtag + n + endtag

    }
    str = str + "</div>"

    $("#main").append(str)
  }
  $(".pixels").css("background-color", "red")
  $(".pixels").css("width", pixx)
  $(".pixels").css("height", pixy)

};
createGrid(10, 10, 10, 10)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div canvas="canvas" id="main">

</div>
```

Comment: `div`s should not be children of `span`s (as long as the `span`s are inline and the `divs` are not...)

Comment: `<div>` elements are block elements by default, if you want them to appear inline then you need to chainge their `display` css property. But you don't, at least not in your fiddle

Comment: thats all good patrick, but what would i change the display property to get that done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`span` should be inside the `div` and make them inline-block to be able to specify width/height

```js
var createGrid = function(dimx,dimy,pixx,pixy){
for(var n = 1; n <dimy+1; n++){
 var str = "<div>"

  for(var i=1;i<dimx+1;i++){
   var opentag = "<span class='pixels' x='"
     var midtag = "' y='"
     var endtag = "'></span>"
     str = str+opentag+i+midtag+n+endtag
      
  }
    str=str+"</div>"

    $("#main").append(str)
   }
$(".pixels").css("background-color","red")
$(".pixels").css("width",pixx)
$(".pixels").css("height",pixy)

};
createGrid(10,10,10,10)
```

```css
#main {
  font-size:0; /* To fix white-space issue*/
}

.pixels {
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div canvas="canvas" id="main">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The parent element should be `display: block` and the inner elements could be `display: inline-block` for them to display in a grid-like manner. Changing only the CSS:

```js
var createGrid = function(dimx, dimy, pixx, pixy) {
  for (var n = 1; n < dimy + 1; n++) {
    var str = "<span class='inline'>"

    for (var i = 1; i < dimx + 1; i++) {
      var opentag = "<div class='pixels' x='"
      var midtag = "' y='"
      var endtag = "'></div>"
      str = str + opentag + i + midtag + n + endtag

    }
    str = str + "</span>"

    $("#main").append(str)
  }
  $(".pixels").css("background-color", "red")
  $(".pixels").css("width", pixx)
  $(".pixels").css("height", pixy)

};
createGrid(10, 10, 10, 10)
```

```css
.inline {
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
}

.pixels {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div canvas="canvas" id="main">

</div>
```

But it would be better to put `span`s inside `div`s, not the other way around (divs are `display: block` by default):

```js
var createGrid = function(dimx, dimy, pixx, pixy) {
  for (var n = 1; n < dimy + 1; n++) {
    var str = "<div>"

    for (var i = 1; i < dimx + 1; i++) {
      var opentag = "<span class='pixels' x='"
      var midtag = "' y='"
      var endtag = "'></span>"
      str = str + opentag + i + midtag + n + endtag

    }
    str = str + "</div>"

    $("#main").append(str)
  }
  $(".pixels").css("background-color", "red")
  $(".pixels").css("width", pixx)
  $(".pixels").css("height", pixy)

};
createGrid(10, 10, 10, 10)
```

```css
.pixels {
  display: inline-block
}

#main > div {
  height: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div canvas="canvas" id="main">

</div>
```

Comment: thankyou, this works, but it creates white linebreaks, how do i stop this from happening? do i move them with margins/padding?

Comment: Add `height: 10px` to the style of the parent element, see edit

Comment: adding height:10px is a hack, not a good idea .. add `overflow:hidden` and you will see what happen ... the line-break is due to font-size/line-height and the fact that inline-block are treated like text. So you should decrease the line-height or the font-size

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: flex` on `canvas` div.
And no need of making the inline element as span, make it a div instead.

```js
/*
$("#body").append(
"<div x='1'></div>"
);
$("div[x=1]").css("background-color","red")
$("div[x=1]").css("width","16")
$("div[x=1]").css("height","16")
*/
var createGrid = function(dimx, dimy, pixx, pixy) {
  for (var n = 1; n < dimy + 1; n++) {
    var str = "<div class='inline'>"

    for (var i = 1; i < dimx + 1; i++) {
      var opentag = "<div class='pixels' x='"
      var midtag = "' y='"
      var endtag = "'></div>"
      str = str + opentag + i + midtag + n + endtag

    }
    str = str + "</div>"

    $("#main").append(str)
  }
  $(".pixels").css("background-color", "red")
  $(".pixels").css("width", pixx)
  $(".pixels").css("height", pixy)

};
createGrid(10, 10, 10, 10)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div canvas="canvas" id="main" style="display: flex;">

</div>
```

Comment: definitely you see flexbox everywhere :)

Comment: Hahaha,, Yups I do,,, ;)